# Sharepoint 2013 Content Link not showing up when entered for specific characters

Tags: sharepoint-server

So in my Site Contents, I have a Content where I add links that show up in my homepage. when adding a new link/item - it prompts me to enter a "Link Name" & Link url. The Link name is the text that appears in my homepage. For some reason, Certain link names don't show up if they start with a certain character like T or V.

Example: When I enter a Link name 'Test' or 'Tango' it  doesn't show up. But if I add like a '.Test' or 'C-Test' it shows up.

Any clues?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have dona a test in my SharePoint 2013 and i can not reproduce your issue:

In the home page, edit page->insert Link, choose From Address, set text to "test", Address to a URL:

[image]

[image]

For your issue:
Try to use another browser and compare the results.

Add the link in another page and compare the results.

Add another link to the home page and compare the results.